# mysql 5.7 json_extract with key for all results in products table

Tags: mysql, json

I need filter products through the json field features:

```
id | name_product | features|
```

field features:

```
[{
    "en": "System Operation",
    "it": "Sistema operativo",
    "value": "IOS 8"
}, {
    "en": "Memory Ram",
    "it": "Memoria Ram",
    "value": "16 Gb"
}, {
    "en": "display",
    "it": "schermo",
    "value": "5.5\""
}]
```

Some products have some features in common, for filter I try this:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE json_extract(features,'$[*].value') = "IOS 8";
```

and:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE 'IOS 8' = json_extract(features,'$[*].value');
```

but the result is the same: NULL
If I put location in array instead of *:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE json_extract(feature,'$[1].value') = "IOS 8";
```

I have the result, the problem is: I dont know where is in exactly the position. In some products `$[1].value` in others `is $[2].value` in others `$[10].value`
`$[*].value` is the best but is null :(
How can fix this problem?
Thank you!!

Comment: what about `JSON_SEARCH()` before that? this will give you the key position within the array.

Comment: Thanks for informing about the JSON functions added in mysql 5.7+

Comment: thank you for answer! Ok I try this: SELECT * FROM products WHERE feature->$json_search("all", "IOS 8"); and this: SELECT * FROM products WHERE json_search(features, 'all', 'IOS 8'); where am I wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```js
mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `products`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.18 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `products`(
    ->   `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ->   `name_product` VARCHAR(50),
    ->   `features` JSON,
    ->   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.24 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `products`
    ->     (`name_product`, `features`)
    -> VALUES
    ->     ('product 1',
    ->      '[
    '>        {"en": "System Operation", "it": "Sistema operativo", "value": "IOS 8"},
    '>        {"en": "Memory Ram", "it": "Memoria Ram", "value": "16 Gb"},
    '>        {"en": "display", "it": "schermo", "value": "5.5\'\'"}
    '>      ]'),
    ->      ('product 2',
    ->      '[
    '>        {"en": "System Operation", "it": "Sistema operativo", "value": "IOS 7"},
    '>        {"en": "Memory Ram", "it": "Memoria Ram", "value": "16 Gb"},
    '>        {"en": "display", "it": "schermo", "value": "5.5\'\'"}
    '>      ]'),
    ->      ('product 3',
    ->      '[
    '>        {"en": "Memory Ram", "it": "Memoria Ram", "value": "16 Gb"},
    '>        {"en": "display", "it": "schermo", "value": "5.5\'\'"},
    '>        {"en": "System Operation", "it": "Sistema operativo", "value": "IOS 8"}
    '>      ]');
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.05 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT `id`, `name_product`, `features`
    -> FROM `products`
    -> WHERE JSON_SEARCH(`features`, 'all', 'IOS 8', NULL, '$[*].value') IS NOT NULL;
+----+--------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | name_product | features                                                                                                                                                                                     |
+----+--------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | product 1    | [{"en": "System Operation", "it": "Sistema operativo", "value": "IOS 8"}, {"en": "Memory Ram", "it": "Memoria Ram", "value": "16 Gb"}, {"en": "display", "it": "schermo", "value": "5.5''"}] |
|  3 | product 3    | [{"en": "Memory Ram", "it": "Memoria Ram", "value": "16 Gb"}, {"en": "display", "it": "schermo", "value": "5.5''"}, {"en": "System Operation", "it": "Sistema operativo", "value": "IOS 8"}] |
+----+--------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Since you took the time to do all this you may consider using an SQL Fiddle in the future. http://sqlfiddle.com/ (that said, apparently it wouldn't of worked anyway since it doesn't support 5.7 yet) Great answer btw!

Comment: @JaredBeekman: Usually I use [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) in my answers, however, as you said, there is currently no support for MySQL 5.7.